# Using Entity Framework dynamically sort by a column in a child

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I call dynamically sort rows of a table when the orderby column is in the parent table doing the following...

```
public List<ServiceRequest> SortSRsByParentFields(string p_Criteria, 
                                                  bool p_sortDescending,
                                                  bool p_ShowAll = true) {

    var propertyInfo = typeof(ServiceRequest).GetProperty(p_Criteria);
    var sortedList1 = new List<ServiceRequest>();
    var sortedList2 = new List<ServiceRequest>();

    var myServiceRequests = GetMyServiceRequests();
    var otherServiceRequests = GetOthersServiceRequests();

    if (p_sortDescending)
    {
      sortedList1 = myServiceRequests
        .AsEnumerable()
        .OrderByDescending(x => propertyInfo.GetValue(x, null)).ToList();

      sortedList2 = otherServiceRequests.AsEnumerable()
        .OrderByDescending(x => propertyInfo.GetValue(x, null))
        .ThenBy(x => x.Client.LastNameFirst).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
      sortedList1 = myServiceRequests.AsEnumerable()
         .OrderBy(x => propertyInfo.GetValue(x, null)).ToList();
      sortedList2 = otherServiceRequests.AsEnumerable()
         .OrderBy(x => propertyInfo.GetValue(x, null))
         .ThenBy(x => x.Client.LastNameFirst).ToList();
    }

    var allSRs = p_ShowAll == false ? sortedList1.Concat(sortedList2).Take(1000)
        .ToList() : sortedList1.Concat(sortedList2).ToList();
    return allSRs;
  }
```

But I can't seem to make this method work if the orderby column is in a child table (a table related to the parent though an FKey).

So the question is how do I make that work?

Answer (score 0):

EF isn't really designed with dynamic sorting in mind. But there are alternatives you can use for cases like this without replacing the rest of your EF code.

For example, with [Tortuga Chain](https://github.com/docevaad/Chain) you can write:

```
ds.From("ServiceRequests", [filter]).WithSorting (new SortExpression(p_Criteria, p_sortDescending)).ToCollection<ServiceRequest>().Execute();
```

You can also just generate SQL directly, but I don't recommend that approach because you have to carefully check the sort expression to ensure it is actually a column name and not a SQL injection attack.